# Solving for a variable in Maple

Tags: c, matlab, maple

In Maple, does anyone know if a function exists to solve for a variable? For example, I am trying to solve `solve4r=(M-x^y)*(r^(-1)) mod (p-1)` for r. So I know the values for M,x,y, and p but don't know r and I am trying to figure that our. How would I do that?

Also, I am not looking for exclusive Maple command. Can be with c or MATLAB since both programs can handle fairly large integers. I am working with numbers that are in size of 30-50 digits long.

Comment: What is "solve4r"? Is that a variable?

Comment: I do not know how to solve for both both `r` and `p` using one equation. Do you think it would be possible to solve for 2 unknowns using one equation here? Tried `solve4r := (M-x^y)*(r^(01))mod(p-1); subs({M=5,x=7,y=9},solve4r); solve(%,p);`

Answer (score 0):

My first thought mirrors Carl's comment: what is `solve4r`? Is it known, or a variable, or...?

I am wondering whether one of the following is similar to what you are trying to accomplish.

Guess 1:

```
restart:                                               

eq:=solve4r=(M-x^y)*(r^(-1));

                                             y
                                        M - x
                        eq := solve4r = ------
                                          r

p:=6:

msolve( eval(eq,[solve4r=14568,M=78646234442,x=3,y=5]), p-1);

                                {r = 3}
```

Guess 2:

```
restart:

eq:=solve4r*r=(M-x^y);

                                              y
                       eq := solve4r r = M - x

p:=6:

sols:={msolve( eval(eq,[M=78646234442,x=3,y=5]), p-1)};

                                           4
    sols := {{r = r, solve4r = 4/r}, {r = -------, solve4r = solve4r}}
                                        solve4r

r=eval(r,select(hastype,sols,identical(solve4r)=identical(solve4r))[1]);

                                     4
                              r = -------
                                  solve4r

msolve( eval(%,solve4r=14568), p-1 );

                                {r = 3}
```